# Use iphone to connect to Wi-Fi and share connection to USB

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, network, wifi

How to share Wifi connection from iphone to mac?

I would like to know if an Iphone can share its Wi-Fi internet connection over its USB connection.(IE Use the phone as a wifi card for a mac)

Comment: This is the wrong place for this question. But yes, it is possible. Activate "Settings -> Personal Hotspot" on the device. Than find "iPhone USB" in your macs System Preferences -> Network

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible, at least not without jailbreaking or a dedicated app. I do not really know, if apps are allowed to create an network interface over USB.

Comment: So the iphone can only use the personal to share an internet connection from 3G/4G?

Comment: yes, only the mobile network connections can be shared. I don't know if this is just a software restriction (jalibreak could break that then) or the wifi adapter actually isn't capable of doing these two things at the same time.